# Use the result of a loop in another loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I want to loop each number in column A through column B.
If there is a match, that number to be looped through column C.
If there is a match, I want the results to be returned in columns E and F.
Each column will have a variable amount of rows. There can also be multiple results.

In my example the number 1 from column A is looped through column B. If a match is found 1 is now looped through column C. If there is a match then columns E and F = C and D.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6S4Y.png)

Comment: Please always show your code!

Comment: You really should read [ask]. Your question is confusing. What does "I want to match the numbers from tab 1, Column A to tab 2, Column A." mean? When you say "All of the columns will be varying lengths" does that mean the data in the column is varying in length, or does it mean the number of columns varies, or does it mean that the number of rows in the column varies? etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Where is your **code**? You know, the stuff you claim you wrote and that isn't working to your expectations? Without seeing the code you wrote (with an appropriate narrative regarding what is is not doing that you expect it to do) your question comes off as just another cheazy, lazy, idiotic, parasitic and (finally) whiny plea to have someone do your work for you. Perhaps you could take a few minutes to rectify that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*I know I am missing a pretty simple concept here. But I cannot seem to get my code to work or find an answer after searching.*' is **not** a specific programming problem and adding narrative debris like '*I can provide my attempted code if that can make things more clear.*' does nothing to change that until **the code is edited into the original post**.

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity for your constructive responses. I tried to clarify my question and will pay more attention to this in the future. Both Dy.Lee and Raunak Thomas answered my question perfectly.

Comment: @ks9 - The purpose of Stack Overflow is to provide a repository of quality questions and answers for the community. At this point, even with your edit, this is a poor quality question and it provides little value to the community. It would be valuable if you could re-edit the question and see if you could clarify it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is arranged like bellow picture,then the code would be like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB1, vDB2, vDB3, vR()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long

    vDB1 = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    vDB2 = Range("b2", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    vDB3 = Range("c2", Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Range("e2:f2").Resize(Rows.Count - 1) = Empty
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB1, 1)

        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB2, 1)
            If vDB1(i, 1) = vDB2(j, 1) Then
                For k = 1 To UBound(vDB3, 1)
                    If vDB1(i, 1) = vDB3(k, 1) Then
                        n = n + 1
                        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 2, 1 To n)
                        vR(1, n) = vDB3(k, 1)
                        vR(2, n) = vDB3(k, 2)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    If n > 0 Then
        Range("e2").Resize(n, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to qualify a parent worksheet here and there.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I have been practicing arrays so this helps a lot. There are a few things in here that I will need to look up to gain a better understanding of, which will help out with my learning process even more.

Comment: @ks9: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that should do the job. But if Tab1/Tab2 values are not unique then it might do a lookup multiple times. For example if there was 1 in place of 9 in Tab 2 it would show the row with 1 twice in tab 4. If you want to avoid that you will need to modify my code

```
Set tab1_list = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B6:B10")
Set tab2_list = Sheets("sheet1").Range("C6:C10")
Set tab3_list_lookup = Sheets("sheet1").Range("E6:E10")
Set Tab3_List_value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("F6:F10")

Set output_location = Sheets("sheet1").Range("H6")

For Each cell1 In tab1_list
    For Each cell2 In tab2_list

    If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then

    For index_no = 1 To tab3_list_lookup.Cells.Count

    If tab3_list_lookup.Cells(index_no).Value = cell2.Value Then

    output_location.Value = tab3_list_lookup.Cells(index_no).Value
    output_location.Offset(0, 1) = Tab3_List_value.Cells(index_no).Value
    Set output_location = output_location.Offset(1, 0)

    End If

    Next index_no

    End If

    Next cell2


Next cell1
```

Comment: Hey Raunak, thanks for your answer and explanation. This works great as well.